# MATLAB: Find max value in each interval of array data?

Tags: arrays, matlab, max

I have an array which stored samples of a signal during a period of time which called `signalArray(1:n)` and `n` is number of samples.

I'm going to split signal samples to several time-segments e.g. M segments `(0:n/M)`, `(n/M+1:2n/M+1)`,`....` and I want to find maximum value of signal in each of theses M segments.

Are there any efficient methods for this?

Comment: Can we assume `M` divides `n`?

Comment: @LuisMendo It may happen that M does not divides n.

Comment: Then your poblem is not well defined. Do you simply want a final, shorter segment of which you also compute the maximum?

Comment: @LuisMendo It would be preferred to be like this.

Comment: Sure, it can be done. Do you need to specify `M` as the number of segments (including the last, possibly shorter segment), or as the segment length (except for the possibly shorter last segment)?

Comment: @LuisMendo As you did in your answer, M would be number of segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `M` were assured to divide `n` you would only need to reshape the data into an `M`-row matrix, to trasnform each segment into a column, and then take the maximum of each column.

In general, if `M` doesn't necessarily divide `n`, the same procedure can be applied but the the last segment (i.e. column) may need to be padded with `NaN` entries. This works because [`max`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) ignores `NaN` values.

```
n = 21;                   % Data size
M = 4;                    % Number of segments. If M doesn't divide n, the last 
                          % segment will be shorter (and will be padded by NaN)
signalArray = rand(1,n);  % Example data
t = NaN(ceil(n/M), M);    % Define matrix of NaN's with required size
t(1:n) = signalArray;     % Fill data (in column-major order). Some entries
                          % in the last column may be left as NaN
result = max(t, [] ,1);   % Maximum of each column
```